# Please tell me Greedy algorithm Time analysis For a problem

Tags: algorithm, analysis, correctness

Assume you are running a transportation network company. Suppose you have M driver and N
passengers such that one driver only picks 1 passenger and 1 passenger can only take ride from 1
driver at a time. To make the travel comfortable, you don’t allow driver to pick up a passenger
with whom he has education difference of more than 2 years. Please devise the algorithm to
maximize the number of drivers and passengers matches.

Comment: Or... alternatively you can tell us what you have thought of first, and we'll tell you how to fix it.

Comment: search for "bipartite matching"

Answer (score 0):

**The Algorithm:**

One greedy approach that you could take would be to sort both lists of M drivers and N passengers by increasing # years of education. You could then use two pointers to assign pairs. Starting at the beginning of each list compare the current driver and passenger. If their education level is <= 2 assign the two as a pair and increment both pointers. If their education level is > 2 increment whichever pointer has the lower education level and continue. Once you have reached the end of both lists you are done assigning pairs. This would assign the maximum number of valid driver-passenger pairs.

**Runtime Analysis:**

Sort List of Drivers: O(M log M)

Sort List of Passengers: O(N log N)

Assigning Pairs: O(N + M)

**Runtime: O(M log M + N log N)**

I hope this information is helpful!